# fstream save file and file system cross-linked files

Tags: c++, winapi, file, filesystems, fstream

Is there a good way to ensure file content is the same you write if your file system have a lot of cross-linked files.

Problem is when i write file content close file and reopen it file corrupted with some other lines from other files. So if i write "AAA" in the file, next time i open file i got: "AAABBBsome stuff".
Code:

```
fstream stream;
stream.open(file_name.c_str(),ios::out | ios::trunc);
if (stream.is_open())
{
  stream.write(content,(streamsize)size);
  stream.close();
}
```

If any one have some ideas please write it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing you can do programmaticly that would help, either create a new file, or ensure that you don't have any cross-linked files (recommended, really, fix your file system)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But another problem is to detect witch software cause cross-linked files even  i fix it they appear again and again.

Comment: @SanjaMelnichuk: Your filesystem should be keeping itself sane, low privilege usermode programs are not supposed to be able to corrupt it. I suspect you either have a buggy FS driver, or possibly some hardware fault (either in your storage, or system memory).